# How do I fetch a specific server by it's ID? [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, chatbot

Here is my code: https://hatebin.com/ljqngujsqq

And I get this error:

`TypeError: message.client.guilds.get is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you're not using the code needed for the latest version of discord.js. You can either stick with discord.js@v11, in which that code will work, or use discord.js@v12, in which you'll need to do it like this:

```js
message.client.guilds.cache.get('Guild ID')
```

For more info, see [`GuildManager#cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache)

Comment: I did that and got this error: message.client.guilds.cache.get(...).then is not a function

Comment: Can you help me with this?

Comment: Which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I am using version v12

Comment: Your error happens because [`GuildManager#cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache) does not return a Promise, and so you can't use `.then`